# Two separated networks with the same ISP

Tags: networking, router

I have one ISP and I want to create two different networks in two different floors. I have 2 wireless routers and the ISP modem which has an integrated router with 4 ethernet ports.

I want the two routers to use the **same internet connection** but they must be **two separated networks** (devices on network1 should not be seen on network2 and vice-versa).

Which of the following counfigurations should be better?

Parallel Configuration:

```
 ______________       ______________
|              |     |              |
|  ISP Modem   |-----|   Router 1   |
|______________|     |______________|
       |              ______________
       |             |              |
       |-------------|   Router 2   |
                     |______________|
```

Cascade Configuration:

```
 ______________       ______________
|              |     |              |
|  ISP Modem   |-----|   Router 1   |
|______________|     |______________|
                      _______|______
                     |              |
                     |   Router 2   |
                     |______________|
```

How should I setup the routers settings to do this? (IPs, Subnets, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel is the way to go. With cascade, device in the network connected to Router 2 can access everything connected to Router 1. Service discovery won’t work because it’s a different broadcast domain, but that’s it. If you know the address(es) or actively scan, everything is accessible.

Comment: With parallel it should not be possible to access devices on the other network then? Will I have to look to some settings in particular?

Comment: Provided both routers are using SNAT or appropriate firewall settings, yes. All consumer-grade routers are configured that way by default, to protect computers on the local network from whatever is crawling around the Internet.